# htaccess 410 url spam hack requests excluding site generated request

Tags: web-crawlers, mod-rewrite, spam, 410-gone

Our site was hacked and links to random content where added to the site. We completely removed the hacked site and put a new one in its place. Everything new including images and content, no other part of the old site was used.

The problem we have now is that the hacker has submitted 100,000's of links to the search bots and the server is continuously visited every 1 second by the bots trying to index the links that don't exist and have never existed on the old and the new site.

We have tried to combat this using the htaccess file of the site with several instances of various conditions and rewrite rules that tell the bots the content is gone.

Example

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/product/.*
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

The trouble with this is that some requests are getting through and producing 301 and 404 errors.

This is causing the bots to retest the request again and report our site as having 100,000s of bad links.

I am looking for a solution that returns 410 code to the bots for all requests excluding all source requests that our actually part of the site.

The site only has approx 10 pages but is a Joomla CMS so there are a mass of resources that get loaded in the background to deliver the page.

My idea was to visit each page in the site and use the browsers inspect to gather a list of all resource requests that a page makes.

The question is how do I formulate this into conditions and rules for the htaccess so that all page requests including route / are delivered but the hackers links requested by the bot aren't?

Also we are working on sending emails to the bot's to say their requests are being instigated by the hacker.

Comment: A 410 status is not significantly different than a 404 status as far as search engine bots go.   The biggest difference is that they will give a 24 grace period before de-indexing 404 pages.   There is no need to ensure that every request for the spam gets a 410.

Comment: An alternate solution: Optimize your 404 page so that it puts much less strain on your server. Then your server will be able to deal with all the 404 requests just fine, until the bots back off.

Comment: If some URLs are giving 404 then the search engine bot has to a second call to my server to verify a 410 status should be given. I'm aiming for a one hit and done as there are 100,000's of spam urls. If I could get all spam urls returning 410 and get the search engine bot to speed up there requests then I can clear the problem quicker. Can I use anything in the robot.txt file to request the speed of a bots indexing?

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to send a 410 instead of a 404.

Possibly the easiest method (if you are familiar with Joomla) is to override the `error.php` file in your template and manually set a 410 status when a 404 has already been determined. For example, at the top of your `error.php` file, something like this:

```
if ($this->error->getCode() == '404'){
    header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone");
}
```

Alternatively, since you only have about 10 pages, you could do this in `.htaccess` by creating a white-list of your page URLs and trigger a 410 if the requested URL does not match your white-list and does not exist as a physical file. This also avoids the request being slowed down by Joomla (pros and cons - see end).

For example:

```
# Whitelist of page URLs 
# NB: Last condition must not have an OR flag
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/second-page [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/third-page [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/fourth-page [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/fifth-page [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/
RewriteRule . - [E=PAGE_URL:yes]

# Send 410 Gone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|svg|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PAGE_URL} !yes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ - [G]
```

This assumes the home page (ie. `/`) is a valid page URL. The `G` (`gone`) flag is shorthand for `R=410` and the `L` flag is not required (it is implied).

The first `RewriteCond` directive excludes URLs that look like static resources (denoted by file extension) from being served a 410 when they don't exist - they should get the default 404. This assumes the spam URLs are not for these types of static resources. If you are getting spam-like requests for nonsense `.css` files for instance then remove that extension from the `RewriteCond` directive or remove the condition entirely to serve a 410 for all these missing resources.

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* eg. `=/second-page`, makes it an exact match string comparison, not a regular expression, so no need to escape regex meta chars etc.

However, this loses your nice user-friendly "Joomla 404 page", so you may need to create one.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Some of the spam urls have this type of structure `/?anything=`

If you want to block any URL that contains a query string then you need a condition that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. Try adding the following:

```
# Block any URL that contains a query string on unknown pages
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{ENV:PAGE_URL} !yes
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```

The single dot regex (that matches a single character) simply checks that there is a query string present.

Comment: In their question they say they have about 10 pages but additional css, js, and images.   They were asking how they could get a list of all the pages and resources to include into .htaccess.

Comment: You don't need to list all static resources that map to physical files as you can simply do a file system check. But I'm also assuming that these "spam" URLs are not for `.css`, `.js` files etc. so these URLs are simply ignored (ie. processed normally).

Comment: Yes the spam urls are also targeting a range of file extensions. When I tried a 410 for the whole site with a single page exception as suggested by MrWhite, the file resources for the page had a 410 reported in the logs and the resource was missing from the page. The homepage / is a valid page URL. I can get all the source paths and build the exceptions using spreadsheet joins based on your example. The thing I'm unsure of is the homepage / exception. Anything other than / or exceptions should give a 410. Example: https://www.example.com/anythingbutexceptions should give a  410.

Comment: While I'm building the resources urls how do I deal with these types of links:
data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzIiIGhlaWdodD0iMzIiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMiAzMiIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTEuNDMzIDE1Ljk5MkwyMi42OSA1LjcxMmMuMzkzLS4zOS4zOTMtMS4wMyAwLTEuNDItLjM5My0uMzktMS4wMy0uMzktMS40MjMgMGwtMTEuOTggMTAuOTRjLS4yMS4yMS0uMy40OS0uMjg1Ljc2LS4wMTUuMjguMDc1LjU2LjI4NC43N2wxMS45OCAxMC45NGMuMzkzLjM5IDEuMDMuMzkgMS40MjQgMCAuMzkzLS40LjM5My0xLjAzIDAtMS40MmwtMTEuMjU3LTEwLjI5IiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmZmZmIiBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjgiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0iZXZlbm9kZCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==

Comment: I've updated my answer... the previous code would have possibly blocked the home page! You really shouldn't have to list all your static resources, if that is what you are suggesting? That would be impossible to manage on anything but the smallest of sites. Static resources are physical files, so you only need to check that the file exists. (Unless you also want to serve 410 for select resources that do exist?!) A data URI is embedded in the document itself - it's not a separate resource.

Comment: I tested the update to your post. I can confirm that static resources don't need listing. Some of the spam urls have this type of structure **/?anything=**  

Which is redirecting with 301 to the homepage.

Comment: You don't use a query string at all on your site? I've updated my my answer. I've also corrected a copy/paste error in my updated code: the first _condition_ on the second rule block should have read `RewriteCond`, not `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. All URLs are SEO so no query strings. Updated " Block any" server is catching them all now and giving them a GONE. Updated "Send 410 Gone". Test reports no errors.

Comment: Just noticed hackers are sending HEAD requests to the none SEO version of a page that exist. The requests are coming from Agent: Wordpress/versionNumber. This are straight from a Wordpress installation. The "Block any query" should take care of these. I've also added deny for each IP.

Comment: Are you sure they are "hackers" that are sending the HEAD requests? _Aside:_ Just because "all URLs are SEO" doesn't mean you don't have query strings.

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Directly or indirectly Yes, I visited the URLs from which the HEADs were requested and they're hacked sites hosted in Azerbaijan with explicit content running on them. Regarding query strings, yes the queries will be in the none SEO address. I've tested all public pages and the "Block any query" doesn't affect them or static sources.

Comment: The administrator is returning 200 then a 303 for login in the logs but the page continues to load the login form. I'm guessing this could caused by "Block any query"

Comment: ... after entering username and password? It's been a while since I've used Joomla - does the admin section use a query string, or is it just the login form. You can create exceptions for one or more URL patterns that should be exempt from the 410.

Comment: Yes there are query strings in the admin url. How do I make an exception for admin/index.php?allquerystring

Comment: Can you not just add another URL to the "whitelist" (ignoring the query string) and add a condition to the rule that blocks query strings? I'll update my answer.

Comment: So, `admin/someNewPath&setOfStaticResources` is all part of the URL-path? In other words all URLs that start `/admin/` should be permitted? If that is the case then just change the _CondPattern_ on the condition that allows _exactly_ `/admin/index.php` to allow all URLs that start `/admin/`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes everything admin/ allow. Every click round admin will give admin/someNewPath&setOfStaticResources. These could be admin/index.php?stringValues or admin/dirPaths/staticResource.

Comment: With the update the admin loads but the resources get 410. I added the specific /dir that was failing and inspect returned no failures. When I post the login the server log records no string values on the end of the url. On a separate test site admin post log shows string values. They must be getting removed.

Comment: "...but the resources get 410" - What URLs are the resources? There's nothing in the code above that would _remove_ anything from the requested URL. (?)

Comment: At the admin login form the resource paths to files and dirs are mixed ^/admin/srcPaths and /media/scr-Paths. I added the /media/ to the whitelist that was flagged as 410, that cleared that issue. On another test site I've looked at what other dirs are required after successful login. Apart from /admin/ and /media/ there's nothing else.

I did find this isn't setting:

set-cookie: someLongNumber.....; path=/; HttpOnly

Comment: Also found Response Cookies 0. Look like the cookie for login isn't being set. Is there anything that could cause that in the current implement htaccess? I will list what in there at the moment below.

Comment: Hi MrWhite,
I appreciative the support provided so far.

Although the solution is doing its job of returning 410 for spam urls, I am locked out of admin for the site and my google adwords are being returned 410.

The solution is stopping the admin login form from setting response cookie and stopping me from accessing admin and its stopping google adwords from accessing the sites pages.

It has rendered the site useless as I can't update it and can't lead customers to it.

Could you help with these issues?